# view details of atq from command line

Tags: php, command-line, at-command

I'm trying to generate a series of AT jobs from a script that logs into a database, gets some info and then loops over it and creates the needed jobs. I cannot seem to figure out the syntax for making it work. Here's what I have:

`$tt_reminder` below is the script i want to run with the arguments appended at the end of the string.

```
$tt_reminder = 'php /public_html/event-registration/scr/fireEventEmail.php' . ' ' . $event->Id . ' ' . 'TeleTraining-Reminder';

$tt2_at is the time that i want to schedule the at job for. 

$tt2_at = '13:00 Feb 20, 2015';
```

This is the command i'm trying to execute the above with:

```
exec('echo -e `'.$tt_reminder.'` | at '.$tt2_at);
```

The problem is, it executes if immediately, rather than scheduling it.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems with your at command.

Firstly, please try to set the date in this format:

```
$tt2_at = '2:30 PM 10/21/2014'
```

and secondly, it is highly recommended to provide the full path to at:

```
exec (echo ... | /usr/bin/at '.$tt2_at);
```

Like shown above, it should run. If you see a message like

```
Garbled time
```

your time string is wrong.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - tried but it's still running the job immediately. it schedules one for the suggested time, but the one in the future does not  run - this is what i see when i run the file.. job 607 at 2015-02-16 15:25

Comment: that's strange. What do you do with the -e option? Might be that it should be behind the php command? I had some problems with at, too. What I did in the end was switching it to using beanstalkd queues - which was a very good decision

Comment: was trying previously to find a way to execute ^d, eof to execute it. didn't work either. i'll check out beanstalkd. thanks for your time....

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at https://github.com/illuminate/queue for laravels queuing module which makes it very very easy to interact with beanstalkd. You will need pheanstalk too, but with that it's as easy as queue:later() and it's working.